# Create android actvity with divider between 2 views

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know exactly how to describe it, but I want to create something like this:

[image: Example wireframe]

Basically it is an activity with 2 views, and you can reveal/hide more of one view by sliding the "slider" up and down.

I have an idea of how I would implement this on my own, but I am wondering if there is some built in widget for this.  The inspiration came from my Sony Experia, where I swipe down to reveal a drawer of notifications.

I thought maybe it was the SlidingDrawer, but that has depreciated in API 17.

Answer (score 0):

[There is no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6467772/1515052) Splitpane or something similar in the current Android API (19 at writing).

But there are existing user created views you could use. For Example [this one](https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout).